# Django form not rendering widget

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I can't figure out, why the django form widget is not rendered in the browser.

**This is my form:**

```
from django import forms
from .models import RealEstateTax

class CreateRealEstateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
        model = RealEstateTax
        fields = ['invoice_number',]
        widget = {
            'invoice_number': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Text goes here'}),
        }
```

Just for testing purposes, I reattributed the field as a Textarea and gave it a class where the text should appear red.

**This is the template:**

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %} Create Realestate Tax {% endblock %}

{% block content %}

<style>
    .form-control {
        color: red;
    }
</style>


<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Send</button>
    </div>
</form>


{% endblock %}
```

When I inspect the element in the browser, there is no class, it is not a Textarea and the text is not red:

[image: Inspected element in the browser]

**This is what I specified in the view:**

```
from realestate.models import RealEstate
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import *
from django.db.models import Sum
from realestate.models import RealEstate
from .forms import CreateRealEstateForm

def create_real_tax(request):
    form = CreateRealEstateForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreateRealEstateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()

    print(form.base_fields)
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'billing/create_real_tax.html', context)
```

I hope you can help me figure this out.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try to change the widget to widgets like this:

```
widgets = {
            'invoice_number': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Text goes here'}),
        }
```

Comment: Wohoo! That's it! 
Thank you, friend!

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `form = CreateRealEstateForm` with `form = CreateRealEstateForm()`.
You are currently only rendering the form if the request is a POST request and simply referencing the class when the request is GET.

Additionally, try changing the form to:

```
class CreateRealEstateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
        model = RealEstateTax
        fields = ['invoice_number',]
        widget = {
            'invoice_number': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Text goes here'}),
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!

Do you mean in the views? 
I tried both outside and inside the if-statement, but on refresh, the outcome was still the same. 

First Try: 

   `form = CreateRealEstateForm() if...`


Second Try: 

    `form = CreateRealEstateForm() if request.method == 'POST': form = CreateRealEstateForm()`

Comment: Yes, I meant the views.py file. I was expecting that to work. Could you also try the following:

    `def create_real_tax(request):
        form = CreateRealEstateForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        print(form.base_fields)
        form = CreateRealEstateForm()
        context = {'form':form}
        return render(request, 'billing/create_real_tax.html', context)`

Comment: Ahh sorry, I think the issue lies in the form. Could you change the form to the following: `class CreateRealEstateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta: 
        model = RealEstateTax
        fields = ['invoice_number',]
        widget = {
            'invoice_number': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'Text goes here'}),
        }
`

Comment: Hello, 

thanks again for the swift response. 
I tried both approaches. Even copy pasted everything, as not to miss a detail. Unfortunately the result is still the same. This is strange.. I wonder what I am missing here

Comment: Hey Mridul, 
thank you so much for helping me. Mahmudul Alam just found it: Instead of `widget`, I had to spell `widgets`
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69245530/12825746

Comment: Haha that pesky s. I really apologise that I couldn’t be of much help.